# How to include stylesheet in the mpdf in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have written a code to display a html in pdf format using mpdf.  I have included for including the stylesheet in mpdf but it is not working. I dnt know whether the path included is wrong.

```
 'mode' => 'utf-8', 
      'format' => 'A4',
      'orientation' => 'P',
      'default_font_size' => 10,
       'default_font' => 'Arial',
      'margin_top' => 20,    
       'margin_bottom' => 20,   
      //'tempDir' => '/tmp'
        );

    
     
      //require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf($mpdfConfig);
       //$this->getFirstPage($mpdf);
       $path = base_url()."reports-assets-new/css/style.css";
       $stylesheet = file_get_contents($path);
       $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
       $mpdf->curlAllowUnsafeSslRequests = true;

       $mpdf->SetHeader('<html><head></head><body><table style="width:100%;border:0;color:#6c757d;"><tr><td style="width:50%;"></td><td style="width:50%; text-align:right;"><img src="'.base_url().'user-images/logo.png" width="53" alt="Smiley face" ></td><tr></table></body></html>');
       $mpdf->setFooter('<html><head></head><body><table style="width:100%;color:#6c757d;"><tr><td style="width:50%;">'.$this->session->userdata('').'</td><td style="width:50%; text-align:right;">'.'{PAGENO}'.'</td><tr></table></body></html>');
  

    $html = $this->load->view('temp/'.$date.'/skil_'.$exam_id.'_'.$uid,$data,true);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
    $this->getLastPages($mpdf);     
    $mpdf->Output('Skillort.pdf', 'D');
```

The above code is for generating a pdf which contains some html code containing styles which are given in another file 'style.css' which is stored in another folder.

Can anyone help me out in this ?

Comment: place the style sheet links in your view file, like I do it for the fonts in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66817784/2275490, also remember css support is practically limited to CSS2

Comment: I have already placed it in the view page but it is not reflecting in the pdf generated. I wanted the styles to reflected in the pdf file generated.